# Buscar registro em outra tabela com mysql e sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Como buscar o registro da coluna `nome` na tabela `categoria`, pelo `id` que foi gravado na tabela `postagens`?

```
const db = require('./db')

const Post = db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
    titulo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    slug: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    descricao: {
        type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    conteudo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    categoria: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    }
})


module.exports = Post
```

Comment: Se a resposta solucionou o seu problema, considere marca-la como solução. Veja mais detalhes em [Como e por que aceitar uma resposta?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/100416)

Answer (score 0):

Para você conseguir fazer esse "join", você deve ter os dois modelos associados, logo `postagens.categoria` será uma *foreign key*.

Então você pode dar um `include` no `findAll` do seu `Post` indicando para incluir o modelo da sua `categoria`, indicando um *alias* (opcional) e o atributo desejado.

```
Post.findAll({
    include: [{
        model: Categoria,
        as: 'categoria', // Caso você tenha dado um "alias" na associação
        attributes: ['nome']
    }]
})
```

A resposta será algo como:

```
[
    {
        // Campos do seu modelo Post
        "titulo": "Titulo",
        "slug": "Slug",
        "descricao": "Descrição",
        "conteudo": "Conteúdo",
        "categoriaId": "ID da categoria",

        // O que você colocou no includes:
        "categoria": {
            "nome": "Nome da categoria"
        }
    }
]
```

Você pode ver mais alguns detalhes neste [documento](https://gist.github.com/zcaceres/83b554ee08726a734088d90d455bc566) no GitHub.

Não encontrei exemplos na documentação oficial do **Sequelize**, mas você pode ver a documentação sobre [associações](https://sequelize.org/v5/manual/associations.html) pra entender melhor como funciona.